# Fast Summation over $\frac{n^2}{k^2}$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, summation, contest-math

How to find $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \lfloor\frac{n^2}{k^2}\rfloor$ where n is of order $10^{18}$?

I have been able to calculate it for n of order $10^{14}$ by using fast-summation, but it does not seem to be just fast enough for $10^{18}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Why did you use the `mobius-function` tag?

Comment: What's the highest time complexity acceptable for your question?

Comment: I guess your "fast-summation" is $O(n^{2/3})$, but for $n=10^{18}$, we're speaking of hours, then.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco The time limit I have is around 2 seconds, so around O($n^{\frac{1}{3}}$) would work.

Comment: You're familiar with the [“Contest problem” policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy), aren't you?